# Tengo problema en imprimir Strings usando JOptionPane, estoy usando netbeans

Tags: java, poo, joptionpane

- 

> `texto en negrita`
> Estoy haciendo un programa para capturar los datos de una persona, añadí colores pero me marca error y también me marca error cuando los quiero imprimir, cabe mencionar que todo los atributos son Strings y estoy utilizando JOptionPane y métodos get y set, a continuación dejo el código:
> *

```js
package Persona;

public class Persona {
    
    private String nombre, apellidoPaterno, apellidoMaterno;
    private String calle, numero, colonia, ciudad, estado;
    private String celular, email, curp;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidoPaterno() {
        return apellidoPaterno;
    }

    public void setApellidoPaterno(String apellidoPaterno) {
        this.apellidoPaterno = apellidoPaterno;
    }

    public String getApellidoMaterno() {
        return apellidoMaterno;
    }

    public void setApellidoMaterno(String apellidoMaterno) {
        this.apellidoMaterno = apellidoMaterno;
    }

    public String getCalle() {
        return calle;
    }

    public void setCalle(String calle) {
        this.calle = calle;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getColonia() {
        return colonia;
    }

    public void setColonia(String colonia) {
        this.colonia = colonia;
    }

    public String getCiudad() {
        return ciudad;
    }

    public void setCiudad(String ciudad) {
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public String getCelular() {
        return celular;
    }

    public void setCelular(String celular) {
        this.celular = celular;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCurp() {
        return curp;
    }

    public void setCurp(String curp) {
        this.curp = curp;
    }
    
}
```

```html
package Persona;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class datosPersona {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String entrada;
        String black="\033[30m"; 
        String red="\033[31m"; 
        String green="\033[32m"; 
        String yellow="\033[33m"; 
        String blue="\033[34m"; 
        String purple="\033[35m"; 
        String cyan="\033[36m"; 
        String white="\033[37m"; 
        String reset="\u001B[0m";
        Persona persona = new Persona(); **texto en negrita**Aqui estoy creando a persona
        
        entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombre: ");
        entrada = entrada.toLowerCase();
        entrada = entrada.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + entrada.substring(1);
        persona.setNombre(entrada);
        
        entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Apellido paterno: ");
        entrada = entrada.toLowerCase();
        entrada = entrada.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + entrada.substring(1);
        persona.setApellidoPaterno(entrada);
        
        entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Apellido materno: ");
        entrada = entrada.toLowerCase();
        entrada = entrada.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + entrada.substring(1);
        persona.setApellidoMaterno(entrada);
        
        entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Calle: ");
        while (entrada.isEmpty())
            entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Porfavor ingrese el nombre de la calle. ");
        entrada = entrada.toLowerCase();
        entrada = entrada.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + entrada.substring(1);
        persona.setCalle(entrada);
        
        entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Numero: ");
        while (entrada.isEmpty())
            entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Porfavor ingrese el numero del domicilio. ");
        entrada = entrada.toLowerCase();
        entrada = entrada.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + entrada.substring(1);
        persona.setNumero(entrada);
        
        entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Colonia: ");
        while (entrada.isEmpty())
            entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Porfavor ingrese el nombre de la colonia. ");
        entrada = entrada.toLowerCase();
        entrada = entrada.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + entrada.substring(1);
        persona.setColonia(entrada);
        
        entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ciudad: ");
        while (entrada.isEmpty())
            entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Porfavor ingrese el nombre de la ciudad: ");
        entrada = entrada.toLowerCase();
        entrada = entrada.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + entrada.substring(1);
        persona.setCiudad(entrada);
        
        entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Estado: ");
        while (entrada.isEmpty())
            entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Porfavor ingrese el nombre del estado: ");
        entrada = entrada.toLowerCase();
        entrada = entrada.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + entrada.substring(1);
        persona.setEstado(entrada);
        
        entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Celular: ");
        while (!valida2(entrada))
            entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Porfavor ingrese solo 10 digitos.\n Celular: ");
        persona.setCelular(entrada);
        
        
        entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Email: ");
        while (!verificar_Correo(entrada))
            entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Email invalido\n Ingrese su Email nuevamente: ");
        entrada = entrada.toLowerCase();
        persona.setEmail(entrada);
        
        entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("CURP: ");
        while (!valida3(entrada))
            entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Porfavor ingrese solo 18 caracteres");
        entrada = entrada.toUpperCase();
        persona.setCurp(entrada);
        
    }
     

    **texto en negrita**Aqui comienza el error
    String persout = cyan + persona.getNombre() + reset + " " +
            blue + persona.getApellidoPaterno() + reset + " " +
            red + persona.getApellidoMaterno() + reset + " \n" +
            
            purple + persona.getCalle() + reset + " num. " +
            yellow + persona.getNumero() + reset + " \n" +
            
            green + persona.getColonia() + reset + " \n" +
            
            cyan + persona.getCiudad() + reset + ", " +
            red + persona.getEstado() + reset + " \n" +
            
            purple + persona.getCelular() + reset + " \n" + 
            
            green + persona.getEmail() + reset + " \n" +
            
            yellow + persona.getCurp() + reset + " \n";
            
       
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, persout); **texto en negrita**Abarca todo esto
            
        public static boolean verificar_Correo(String correo){
            Pattern patron = Pattern.compile("^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-za-z0-9-]+)*@" +
                "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");
            Matcher mat = patron.matcher(correo);
            return mat.find();
        }
    
        public static boolean valida1(String s) {
            
            if(s.isEmpty()) return false;
            
            int len = s.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
                if ((Character.isLetterOrDigit(s.charAt(i)) == false)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    
        public static boolean valida2(String s) {
            
            int len = s.length();
            if(len != 10) return false;
            
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
                if ((Character.isLetterOrDigit(s.charAt(i)) == false)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        
        public static boolean valida3(String s) {
            
            int len = s.length();
            if (len !=18) return false;
            
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
                if ((Character.isLetterOrDigit(s.charAt(i)) == false)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Buenas, Uri, he copiado tu código, lo he ejecutado y no me sale ningún error. No entiendo bien esos códigos de colores que has puesto pero despues de introducir los datos de una persona, se muestra un panel con esos datos introducidos y cómo digo no aparece error ninguno.

Comment: fijate en la llaves "}" estas cerrando la llave del metodo main antes de incluir la linea donde esta ```JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, persout);```

Comment: Bueno, yo daba por supuesto que eso era una errata al copiar el código aquí

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme, si estaba mal colocada una la llave de cierre en el código, y los colores pues decidí quitarlos porque no se aplicaban correctamente.